# Ionic Angular GooglePlus : Invalid provider for the NgModule

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, google-plus

I'm trying to Integrate [GooglePlus](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus) signin to Ionic w/ Angular app.

error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid provider for the
> NgModule 'UsersModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are
> allowed, got: [Keyboard, ?[object Object]?]

users.module.ts

```
...
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...,
    GooglePlus
  ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your import path to:

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
```

You may see a build error:

```sh
An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/google-plus" has missing dependencies:
 - @ionic-native/core
```

Just install the `@ionic-native/core` dependency and you should be good to go.

```sh
npm install @ionic-native/core
```

Last thought, If you have trouble with that Cordova plugin, another option is `@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth`. Simon Grimm has a great blog, [How to add Capacitor Google Sign In to your Ionic App](https://devdactic.com/capacitor-google-sign-in/), which describes all the steps necessary to get Google auth working.

Comment: alright, that's a good alternative, thanks